# Алгоритм формирования jar файла

Tags: java, maven, jar

В jar файле есть папка `META-INF/services`. Вопрос кто и как туда вносит информацию?

Сейчас у меня при сборке одного и того-же проекта при помощи maven и IDEA в нескольких файлах из этой папки оказывается различная информация. В результате проект собранный maven у меня не работает.

maven собирается плагином maven-shade-plugin

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>org.example.Loader</mainClass>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Вот такой путь в исходниках `project/src/main/resources/META-INF/services`. В `pom.xml` ничего особенного. Т.е. всё работает без каких-либо нестандартных настроек pom.xml-я

Comment: @Sergey В исходниках папки META-INF нет вообще. Все и у меня работало на других проектах, а на этом хитрые зависимости плюс активное использование ClassLoader. Вот этот ClassLoader при сборке через maven не подгружает некоторые классы. Точнее он даже не пытается их загружать

Comment: Что мешает создать эту папку? У меня её тоже никогда нет в исходниках, пока сам не сделаю:)

Comment: @Sergey И чем это поможет? Вы вопрос читаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плагин maven-shade-plugin по умолчанию помещает в итоговый jar первый попавшийся файл из META-INF/services зависимых модулей. Но если плагину указать трансформер `org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer`

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>org.example.Loader</mainClass>
                <manifestEntries>
                    <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
        </transformers>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

то тогда при обнаружении в зависимых модулях в папке META-INF/services файлов с одинаковым именем, в конечном jar эти все файлы будут объединены.